# Reflect all possible permutations of a generic type with constraints

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Given a generic type with constraints:

```
class MyClass<T> where T: Alpha
{
}
```

and implementations of that constraint:

```
class Alpha {}
class Bravo : Alpha {}
class Charlie : Alpha {}
```

How can get generic types for all the combinations at run-time?

```
// I want these types at run-time
MyClass<Alpha> 
MyClass<Bravo> 
MyClass<Charlie>
```

**EDIT:**  Based on @rich.okelly's answer, I think the real question is this:

How can I find all the types that implement my generic type's constraint at run-time?

So if I'm given `typeof(MyClass<>)`, I get the types above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
var alphaType = typeof(Alpha);
var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(t => alphaType.IsAssignableFrom(t));
var myClass = typeof(MyClass<>);
foreach (var type in allTypes) 
{
  var genericType = myClass.MakeGenericType(type);
}
```

Alternatively, if the generic types have already been loaded:

```
var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes()).Where(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(MyClass<>));
foreach (var type in allTypes) 
{
  ...
}
```

**Update**

You can use [the `GetGenericArguments()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) and [the `GetGenericParameterConstraints()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints.aspx) to get the required types.

```
var myType = typeof(MyClass<>);
var typeConstraints = myType.GetGenericArguments().First().GetGenericParameterConstraints();
var allTypes = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes());
var genericTypes = allTypes.Where(t => typeConstraints.All(tc => tc.IsAssignableFrom(t))).Select(t => myType.MakeGenericType(t));
foreach (var type in genericTypes)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ideas if all you're given is the `MyClass` type?

Comment: Updated so runtime type of alpha is not required.

Comment: @AustinSalonen answer now updated to complete solution (assuming all required assemblies have been loaded).

Comment: Spot on with what I need!  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for that; been looking for something to help me with this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053665/c-sharp-generics-wrapper-generator.  Your solution might be the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all loaded assemblies in the app domain.  And then enumerate all the types in each Assembly and test to see if each type is a [subclass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.issubclassof.aspx) of the constant.